# Can't set a login page in Spring

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-boot, authentication

I have created a Spring Boot Application which has a SPA page with all the functionality and a Login Page which is the first page of the App. My trouble is that the Login page is not being rendered by the controller at all.

Below is my controller code.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index() {
    return "index.html";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome/")
public String login() {
    return "login.html";
}
```

}

I have stored both the login page and index.html page at the same location.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use thymeleaf in spring-boot, just add `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency, and move `login.html` `index.html` to `resources/templates/login.html` `resources/templates/index.html`.
Login controller should be rewritten:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome/")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```